# How to insert a link into this PHP code from a WP Theme

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using a WP theme that has a FA icon in the header.

The icon can be customized from the Theme Customization page.

I would like to convert this icon into a button link (by just adding the link like href="#", that's all), no need to change styles or behavior.

This is a demo of the WP Theme:

http://wp-themes.com/arcade-basic/?TB_iframe=true&width=600&height=400

And here you have the code for that particular section in the header template:

```
     <?php if ( $bavotasan_theme_options['header_icon'] ) { ?>

     <i class="fa <?php echo $bavotasan_theme_options['header_icon'];?>"></i>

     <?php } else { 

        $space_class = ' class="margin-top"';

     } ?>
```

Can't make any linking inside the i tag to work.

Thanks in advance.

-Marcelo

Comment: You just need to put a link tag around it. `<a href="#"><i class="fa"></i></a>`

Comment: Any time the theme is updated that would be overwritten. Better to create a child theme and use functions.php to make the change: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes